# Creating Activity using CreateNewActivityEntry of CrmServiceClient

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am calling the **CreateNewActivityEntry()** method in the **CrmServiceClient**. The method always returns an empty Guid and does not throw an error.  The activity record is never created.

Example code:

```
/// <param name="activityTypeName">Part of the ActivityTypes option set.  Ex: Email, Phone, Task</param>
/// <param name="entityTypeName">For example:  Contact, Lead, Realtor Office</param>
/// <returns>The ActivityID of the new activity or Guid.Empty if it fails</returns>
public Guid CreateNewActivityForContact(string activityTypeName, string entityTypeName, Guid contactID, string subject, string description, Guid createdByID)
{
    Guid tmpRet = Guid.Empty;
    if (contactID != null)
    {
        CrmServiceClient tmpSvc = MyCompany.CRM.ServiceReference.Crm.CreateCrmService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMServiceURL"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMOrganization"]
            , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMServiceUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMServicePassword"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMServiceDomainName"], 0, "");

        //this is not creating the record but not throwing an error either
        tmpRet = tmpSvc.CreateNewActivityEntry(activityTypeName, entityTypeName, contactID, subject, description, createdByID.ToString());
    }
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("ContactID cannot be null");

    return tmpRet;
}
```

We use other methods on this service so I know the service works.

The parameters all contain values that I believe are correct, but I have not been able to find any examples of implementing this method anywhere.

Does anyone have experience using the **CreateNewActivityEntry** method and can help?

Here is some relevant version info:

- Using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Version: 8.1.0.359
- Application version: .NET version 4.6.1
- SDK version from NuGet:  Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly package version 8.2.0.1

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I'm going to go ahead and answer my own post.  The solution to this was passing in the "activityTypeName" parameter as all lowercase.  Apparently the CRM API only likes to work with lowercase entity names.  I was passing in "Task" as the activityTypeName, but changed it to "task" and it worked.

Thanks Microsoft for making an SDK that is so poorly documented.  Would it have been too freaking hard to create **ONE** example per method in the help documentation?